# JQuery Ajax to Fetch Conversion clarificartions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch

I have a ajax wrapper functions in my project. I'll be calling this wrapper function to perform ajax requests in my application. Now I'm planning to change this to use fetch. But since I'm new I got some questions inside me. I believe this question we helpful to people who is planning to move from Jquery Ajax to Fetch. Here is the code and questions.

My old Jquery Ajax wrapper function:

```js
function ajaxGetAsync(requestUrl, postData, global, datatype) {
    try {
        var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: datatype,
            url: requestUrl,
            async: true,
            global: global,
            headers: {
                "XSRF-TOKEN": $('#_AjaxAntiForgeryTokenForm input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            data: postData,
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXhr);

                handleShowInformationBox('Error', errorThrown, 'OK');
            }
        });
    } catch (q) {
        ajaxIndicatorStop();
    }

    return false;
};

function ajaxFormPostAsync(requestUrl, form, global = true) {
    try {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: requestUrl,
            async: true,
            global: global,
            headers: {
                "XSRF-TOKEN": $('#_AjaxAntiForgeryTokenForm input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            data: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(document.querySelector(form))).toString(),
            success: function () {
                handleHideValidationErrors(form);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXhr);

                handleShowInformationBox('Error', errorThrown, 'OK');
            }
        });
    } catch (q) {
        ajaxIndicatorStop();
    }

    return false;
};
```

Here is how I configured Ajax Globals for displaying/hiding loaders:

```js
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    ajaxIndicatorStart('Loading');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    ajaxIndicatorStop();
});
```

Now i call the above method to Get HTML/JSON from server as follows,

```js
$.when(ajaxGetAsync(url, { id: Id }, true, window.htmlDataType)).done((response) => {
      document.querySelector('#someDiv').innerHTML = response;                                
});

$.when(ajaxPostAsync(url, { id: Id }, true, window.jsonDataType)).done((response) => {
      console.log(response);                               
});
```

Note that I'll change datatype to  `window.jsonDataType` to get json data. Similarly I call my `ajaxFormPostAsync` This works fine.

Here is the fetch equivalent:

My new Fetch wrapper function:

```js
async function fetchGetAsync(requestUrl, postData, global, dataType) {
    return await fetch(requestUrl,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                "XSRF-TOKEN": $('#_AjaxAntiForgeryTokenForm input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            body: postData
        }
    ).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        handleShowInformationBox('Error', error, 'OK');
    });
}

async function fetchFormPostAsync(requestUrl, form, global) {
    return await fetch(requestUrl,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
                "XSRF-TOKEN": $('#_AjaxAntiForgeryTokenForm input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            body: new FormData(document.querySelector(form))
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            handleShowInformationBox('Error', error, 'OK');
        });
}
```

How to configure globals to display/hide loaders? 
How to specify datatype in fetch api?

I tried calling the above method as follows,

```js
await fetchGetAsync(url, { id: Id }, true, window.htmlDataType).then((response) => {
     document.querySelector('#someDiv').innerHTML = response;                                
})

await fetchFormPostAsync(url, targetForm).then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);            
});
```

This throws error as shown below:

For GET:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with
>   GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

For POST:

> Unexpected end of JSON input

How to get Json/Html using fect api like how I did previously?

Just started learning fetach api with my existing code. Please assist on where I go wrong.

Comment: You need to parametrize all the data into url query string for a GET

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I now understood and made GET part to work. But with POST I'm getting `Unexpected end of JSON input` as error. I have posted the conversion work as answer. Please correct me so that I can update the answer as I learn.

Comment: Did you check the [MDN fetch pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options) already? Also don't edit your question, but rather respond to your own question, as this is a QA, if the Q transforms into an A, then the Q part might be lost

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks for the link. I'll check. Till now I only updated the Q. Once I completely get the answer. I'll post as an answer. I wrongly mentioned in my previous comment and was not able to correct my previous comment. Sorry.

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks for the link. I figured out the issue. Now I got answers for two of my questions. I'm left with showing/hiding loaders. Any equivalent for `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` in fetch?

Comment: They are promise based, so just chain them together 

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks for the support. I finally achieved my conversion from `ajax` to `fetch` and posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some learning and works, Here is how I implemented `fetch` API wrappers in my project along with showing/hiding spinners and removed `ajax` wrappers.

**Fetch GET wrapper:**

```js
async function fetchGetAsync(requestUrl, postData, global, dataType) {
    let query = Object.keys(postData)
        .map(k => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(postData[k]))
        .join('&');
    requestUrl = `${requestUrl}?${query}`;

    if (global) ajaxIndicatorStart('Loading');

    return await fetch(requestUrl,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
                "XSRF-TOKEN": document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return dataType === window.constant.jsonDataType ? response.json() : response.text();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            handleShowDefaultInformationBox(error, 'OK');
        })
        .finally(() => {
            if (global) ajaxIndicatorStop();
        });
}
```

**Fetch POST wrapper:**

```js
async function fetchFormPostAsync(requestUrl, form, global = true) {
    if (global) ajaxIndicatorStart('Loading');

    return await fetch(requestUrl,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
                "XSRF-TOKEN": document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value
            },
            body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(document.querySelector(form)))
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            handleShowDefaultInformationBox(error, 'OK');
        })
        .finally(() => {
            if (global) ajaxIndicatorStop();
        });
}
```

similarly you can construct `fetch` API wrappers for other HTTP verbs and actions.

Then call from your javascript like shown below:

**Calling Fetch GET wrapper:**

```js
await fetchGetAsync(url, { id: Id }, true, window.constant.htmlDataType).then((response) => {
      document.querySelector('#someDiv').innerHTML = response;                                
})
```

**Calling Fetch POST wrapper:**

```js
await fetchFormPostAsync(url, targetForm).then((response) => {
     console.log(response);            
});
```

Thanks to [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) and [Icepickle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3231537/icepickle)  for guidance and support.